show that $E[\tau_2] = 2E[\tau_1]$
Let $X_i$ be iid for all $i\geq 1$ such that $\mathbb P(X_i = 1)=1/2=\mathbb P(X_i = -1)$, then define $\tau_a = min\{ n>0: X_1+...+X_n = a\}$ where $a$ in an integer. Show that $\mathbb E[\tau_2] = 2\mathbb E[\tau_1]$.
Intuitively this makes sense, but I don't know how to formalize my argument.
im basically stuck at $\mathbb E[\tau_2] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[\tau_2 | \tau_1 = n]]$ where $n$ is odd.

Maybe this might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk

You can show $\tau_2-\tau_1$ and $\tau_1$ are iid.  If one assumes $X_i=1$ with probability $p>1/2$, then they become integrable.

Since this is a null-recurrent simple random walk, albeit $\tau_1$ is almost surely finite, has an infinite expectation. The same is true for $\tau_2$ hence the `equality' is in the sense $2\times\infty=\infty$.

sure, do there exists an alternative approach where you exploit the fact that $E[\tau_2|\tau_1 = n]$ for an odd $n$?

For conditional expectation to be even defined, you need the existence of the unconditional one. Hence $\mathbb{E} [\tau_2\mid\tau_1]$ is not even defined at all.  See e.g https://www.math.purdue.edu/~stindel/teaching/ma539/cdt-expectation-2.pdf

i see, why the exercise sheet contained a hint which i mentioned at my 1st comment?

Can you check that you the problem stated as it is written above? Otherwise it is mistake in the problem.

yeah i forgot min in front of the $\tau_a$ definition, but it should not affect the argument

It is still incorrect. The $\min$ should be replaced by $\inf$ as you do not know if the set is empty or not.
